# Possible to open Hammer directly from shortcut?

Tags: steam, hammer

I want to open Hammer(for CS:GO) directly from windows shortcut, without the SDK-launch menu. Is this possible? I've only been able to open the SDK launcher from a shortcut.

And, is it possible to open a map directly as well? So, 1 shortcut that opens Hammer, with a specific map inside of Hammer?

If there exist a launch option for this, then I can use that!

Comment: @ratchetfreak I looked into the situation and I think it belongs here. Map-making tools are [on-topic here (with very strong support)](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here). Arqade [also *says* it is on-topic there (with moderate support)](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/544/do-map-editor-questions-belong-here), but reality differs: [the 1 question on Arqade tagged "hammer"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129879/stuck-in-a-single-2d-view) was closed as off-topic: the comments suggest migrating it here!

Comment: @Anko I see, retracting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, its possible.
Create a shortcut to the hammer.exe and add the -nop4 parameter.
("D:\Steam Games\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\bin\hammer.exe" -nop4)

Comment: It worked. Great! Do you know of any flags that can be used to open maps at launch?